# Is there a way to aggregate values in a Google sheet pivot table using calculated values

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I'm trying to find a way to aggregate values in a Google sheet in a pivot table using calculated values.

Here's my data:

| Close Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| March 2020 | £60,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £15,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £90,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £220,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £50,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £100,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £440,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £15,999.00 |
| May 2020 | £85,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £500,000.00 |
| June 2020 | £270,000.00 |
| June 2020 | £210,000.00 |
| July 2020 | £60,000.00 |
| July 2020 | £35,000.00 |
| July 2020 | £75,000.00 |

and here's the pivot table I'd like to produce, with result in the right hand column I'd like to achieve using a calculated field:

| Close Date | Desired Result |
| --- | --- |
| March 2020 | £60,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £435,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £1,575,999.00 |
| June 2020 | £2,055,999.00 |
| July 2020 | £2,225,999.00 |

I realise I could add an additional formula column in the sheet itself, but I'd much prefer to do this via a calculated field if possible.

I've spent a long time trying to find a solution, and am now wondering if it's possible as you can't reference individual cells in a calculated field.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")), 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A))<=SEQUENCE(1, COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A)))*
 QUERY(A1:B, "select sum(B) where B is not null group by A label sum(B)''")), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A), 1, 1, 0))})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I got that to work! I also just found a similar solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNyoAi7RerM&ab_channel=LearnGoogleSheets%26ExcelSpreadsheets. It's not quite as generic, as it's dependent on dates, but is a little simpler.